# Magento 2.4.5-p1 custom module pageBuilder not editing

Tags: page-builder, magento2.4.5p1

My custom module's in page builder when I click the cog icon nothing happens, no errors in the console either any ideas what it is am I missing something?
[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out all I needed was `<update handle="editor"/>` in the layout form.

Comment: And where in which layout did you add it ? I have the same issue now :D

Comment: @vandenHeuvelConcepts in your `custom_module_edit.xml` file.

Comment: I suppose my issue is different then, got no page builder options in catalog, product, cms page, nowhere ,,, I did make a child theme but I did make a custom module anywhere.

Comment: @vandenHeuvelConcepts in that case check If the module is completely disabled. Or it may have been deactivated in configuration > content management > advanced content tools > enable page builder. Ref https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/page-builder/deactivate-pagebuilder/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this module instead [Goomento - Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder) that will rid off your headache with Magento Page Builder, also come with a ton of features,

Answer (score 0):

For suppose we have a custom module `A2bizz_Design`, where `A2bizz` is Vendor and `Design` is module name -

now the location for you admin form will be - `A2bizz\Design\view\adminhtml\layout\a2bizz_design_edit.xml`

the content of the above xml file should be as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="a2bizz_design_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the above xml `update handle="editor"` is important, which is responsible for making you editing working.

Answer (score 0):

I've this and It's worked for me, If you don't have any layout xml file then, Create default.xml at /Vendor/Extension/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

and write this below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
</page>
```